# JavaScript button click does not work

Tags: javascript, iis

I have a problem with my index.html page -

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>

<button type="button"
onclick="window.alert('hello')">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I deploy it to IIS and open It using http://localhost:80/index.html - the button click works. However if I edit the site bindings to include the server name (XYX) and then load it using my server name http://xyz:80/index.html - the page loads fine  but the javascript button click event does not work. what am I missing ?

Comment: Is there any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would depend on the name you use to load the page.

Comment: No error in the console. Seems to be something related to IIS/Server. I had deployed a MVC website and it behaved the same way. To narrow down the problem , I had created this simple html page.

Comment: If you look at the button in the Elements tab, do you see the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: Was it at the same domain name? If so do you maybe have js blocked for that domain name in the browser settings?

Comment: Could it be because the browser security settings kick in and disallow javascript on insecure remote domains?

Comment: sorry for the late reply , I was able to see that the rendering is fine for Mozila or Chrome. IE did not work properly. Not sure though why . IE 10 / 11 same distorted rendering. Have finally created separate bland view for IE users